# Translation for nested_attributes in polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I'm trying to translate a label of a nested form attribute of a polymorphic model. I'm using Rails 4.
Object relationship:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable,  dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

My form:

```
= form_for @question do |f|
  .form-group
    =f.text_area :body

  = fields_for :attachments do |a|
    .form-group
      = a.label :file
      = a.file_field :file

  = f.submit
```

My ru.yml:

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    question:
      attachment:
        file: Файл
      attachments:
        file: Файл
    attachment:
      file: Файл
```

Doesn't work. What should be the locale structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label

You should try with:

```
helpers:
  label:
    yourmodelname:
      yourmodelattr: "Write your entire text here"
```

This is guessing that your `I18n.locale` is set to `:ru`

Hope this helps you.

Quoting the documentation:

Localization can also be based purely on the translation of the attribute-name (if you are using ActiveRecord):

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    post:
      cost: "Total cost"
```

Output:

```
f.label(:post, :cost)
# => <label for="post_cost">Total cost</label>
```

Comment: I think there should be a way to make it work by properly setting locale file.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I wonder if there is a way to make it work through activerecord model attributes?

Comment: @leemour In the documentation says how to do it if you're using activerecord too. That didn't worked?

Comment: Could you point to the documentation on that? Translating just attributes of a model didn't work, as you can see in my question. I saw some solutions using `model: model/attribute: translation` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I had the same setup. After changing the order of lines it started to work with attributes. Strange) Thanks!